performance - typescript yield is expensive
I'm seeing performance impact by shifting some of typescript code to use IterableIterator and yield.
There is 3x perf impact in this code if we try on typescript playground -
function *foo() {
   for(let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
      yield i
   }
}

let sr = performance.now();
let n = 0;
//for(let c of foo()) {
for(let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
   n += i;
}

console.log(performance.now() - sr);

I have tried it in larger setting and saw the impact was still there. Any options?
